# Populate a field in a network with downstream end node

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I am currently working on a stormwater system with the features in a geodatabase.  I would like run a tool or a script that will go through each outfall (last downstream node) and populate a field within the catch basins (upstream nodes on connected lines).

I can use the network analyst to trace/highlight the upstream nodes but, you have to place a flag for each one and then field calculate.

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean  by "populate a field within the catch basins (upstream nodes on connected lines)"? May be edit your question with an image and the sort of data you are trying to extract?